# Is there any way to detect and differentiate between English language and Roman-Urdu language in python?

Tags: python, nlp, google-colaboratory, language-detection

Basically I have a RomanUrduDataSet (Urdu written with the help of English alphabets e.g Sahi-right) which also includes some English language words. And I have to detect how many words of the English language are included and what are they. In other words, wants to differentiate between two languages i.e English and roman-Urdu both use the same set of alphabets. e.g "Prime Minister Wazeer-azam"

I have tried spacy and spacy_langdetect packages in colab using python it's working good for all other languages but unfortunately including the Roman Urdu words as English language words. Such as for a text **"This is English text sai kaha" in which "sai kaha"** (well said) belongs to roman Urdu but my code below is including it as English language words.

```
import spacy
from spacy_langdetect import LanguageDetector

nlp = spacy.load("en")
nlp.add_pipe(LanguageDetector(), name="language_detector", last=True)
text = "This is English text Er lebt mit seinen Eltern und seiner Schwester in Berlin. Yo me divierto todos los días en el parque. Je m'appelle Angélica Summer, j'ai 12 ans et je suis canadienne."
doc = nlp(text)
# document level language detection. Think of it like average language of document!
print(doc._.language['language'])
# sentence level language detection
for i, sent in enumerate(doc.sents):
    print(sent, sent._.language)
```

**OUTPUT:**
This is English text sai kaha {'language': 'en', 'score': 0.9999982400559537}
Er lebt mit seinen Eltern und seiner Schwester in Berlin. {'language': 'de', 'score': 0.9999979601967207}
Yo me divierto todos los días en el parque. {'language': 'es', 'score': 0.9999976130316337}
Je m'appelle Angélica Summer, j'ai 12 ans et je suis canadienne. {'language': 'fr', 'score': 0.9999962796815557}

***but my desired result is:***

This English text {'language': 'en', 'score':
sai kaha {'language': 'roman-urdu', 'score':

Answer (score 0):

Your comments already say it - this is sentence level language. If you want sai kaha to have a different language it needs to be [its own sentence](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#sbd). So either the DependencyParser model needs to be different, which is used for sentence boundary detection, or you can try to implement your own with Sentencizer.

Comment: Moreover, in roman-Urdu **had** means limit whereas, in English _had_  is used as helping verb and represents past.

Answer (score 0):

You could have SpaCy identify language by n-gram (trigrams in this case would work) with a custom `Sentencizer`

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. N-grams or trigrams would only work when we have two continuous sentences of different languages one after another. The actual problem is word-level detection e.g. **Tum kitny funny ho** only funny is english word rest belongs to roman-URDU .Do you think word2vec can better help in detecting and differentiating two mixed language words?(a partial idea in my mind)